# Alterar o layout de buttons dinamicamente

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho dois buttons na tela, estes ficam ou não visíveis dependendo da situação.
Há uma terceira situação, que deveria deixar os dois visíveis, mas não cabe na tela. Então, gostaria que eles passassem a ficar um ao lado do outro, como fazer isso, no código, dinamicamente?

Segue xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/request_photo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar5"
        android:transitionName="infoboxImage" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/request_photo"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_favorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_off_48px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/request_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_favorite"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Abraao Barros Lacerda"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:transitionName="infoboxName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/request_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/request_name"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="abraaobarros3@gmail.com" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_points"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/request_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/request_name"
            android:text="50.000 pontos" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/request_email"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_interests"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_Points"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/horizontal_scroll">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_first"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.03"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Segunda-feira"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button0"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.03"
                        android:text="Ida - 7:00" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.03"
                        android:text="Volta -18:00" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/card_1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_second"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Quarta-Feira" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Ida - 7:00" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Volta -18:00" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/card_2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/check">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_third"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Quinta-Feira" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Ida - 7:00" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Volta -18:00" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@+id/card_3"
                android:id="@+id/button">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/send_offer_request"
                    style="@style/appButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/card_3"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Oferecer" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/send_ask_request"
                    style="@style/appButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/card_3"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Pedir" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Segue código, o else, deve fazer com que os dois apareçam na tela.

```
    if (user.getProfile() == 0) {
        send_offer_request.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        send_ask_request.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else if(user.getProfile() == 1){
        send_offer_request.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        send_ask_request.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        send_offer_request.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        send_ask_request.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Eles estão dentro de um LinearLayout com `orientation="horizontal"`, por isso deveriam aparecer lado a lado. Experimente mudar , nos dois, `android:layout_width="match_parent"` para `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: @ramaral É o que eu quero fazer, dinamicamente. Pois eles devem ser match_parent, a não ser que estejam lado a lado.

Comment: Se mudar para wrap_content eles cabem na tela?

Comment: @ramaral Cabem, precisaria tb espaçá-los. mas cabem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só foi possível resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
     else {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.card_3);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.card_3);
                params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.send_ask_request);

                send_offer_request.setLayoutParams(params2);
                send_ask_request.setLayoutParams(params);
                send_offer_request.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                send_ask_request.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Agradeço as respostas que me levaram a esta conclusão.

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi correctamente o que pretende é que quando apenas um dos botões está visível ele deve ocupar a largura total do LinearLayout.
Por isso eles são declarados com `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

Quando se pretende que ambos fiquem visíveis eles se sobrepõem, devido ao `match_parent`.

Assim, para os colocar lado a lado, deve alterar o layout_width de match_parent para wrap_content.

Isso é possível recorrendo ao método `setLayoutParams()`:

```
bt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

É no entanto necessário preservar os valores da margem.
Tendo em conta que ele é igual nos dois botões basta guardar um:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginOld = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)send_offer_request.getLayoutParams();

send_offer_request.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
send_ask_request.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginNew_offer = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)send_offer_request.getLayoutParams();
marginNew_offer.topMargin = marginOld.topMargin;

ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginNew_ask = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)send_ask_request.getLayoutParams();
marginNew_ask.topMargin = marginOld.topMargin;
```

Nota: os atributos `android:layout_alignParentBottom`, `android:layout_below` e `android:layout_centerHorizontal`não têm efeito num LinearLayout.

Comment: havia tentado mais cedo dessa forma. e este erro me aparece: 
**android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams**

Comment: mesmo sendo explicito 
`send_ask_request.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`
o erro acontece

Comment: Não vejo razão para esse erro, os botões estão dentro de um LinearLayout, a não ser que o *xml* que postou não seja o que está a usar.

Comment: É este o XML, ainda acrescentei um outro linear layout, por cima de todos os relatives e coloquei este linear, com os botões, sendo filho deste outro linear e o erro permanece.

Comment: segue minha resposta, de como consegui resolver, ainda não entendendo o erro que coloquei no comentário